# In Javascript, How to determine if an object property exists and is not empty?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have the next javascript object:

```
var errors = {
    error_1: "Error 1 description",
    error_2: "Error 2 description",
    error_3: "",
    error_4: "Error 4 description"
};
```

How can I determine if the property `error_1` exists in the `errors` object and is not empty as well?

Comment: Are those error messages going to be only string always?

Comment: @Arvind In my case, they will be only strings. But if you ask to provide some solution for other data types, then that will be great, as me and the others will be able to use what fits for them.

Comment: What does "not empty" mean? Object properties are initialised to the supplied value, their default or *undefined* when created, so are never "empty".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`if (errors.hasOwnProperty('error_1') && errors['error_1'] )`

The method `hasOwnProperty` can be used to determine whether an object has the specified property as a direct property of that object.

The `errors[key]` where `key` is a string value checks if the value exists and is not null

to Check if its not empty where it is a string then `typeof errors['error_1'] === 'string' && errors['error_1'].length` where you are checking for the length of a string

Result:

`if (errors.hasOwnProperty('error_1') && typeof errors['error_1'] === 'string' && errors['error_1'].length)`

Now, if you are using a library like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org) you can use a bunch of utility classes like `_.isEmpty` `_.has(obj,key)` and `_.isString()`

Comment: OP said "not empty" but this will also be true for `0` and `null`

Comment: thanks @Phil just added a String length check if he likes to specifically checks for non empty string

Answer (score 3):

To precisely answer your question (exists and not empty), and assuming you're not referring to empty arrays, you could use

```
typeof errors.error_1 === 'string' && errors.error_1.length
```

Comment: dayum, so just plain old `.length` returns true if it's > 0, else false?  You sure you don't need `length > 0`?

Comment: @RonRoyston yes. In a boolean expression, `0` is *falsy*

Answer (score 3):

Here is a another good answer I [found](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/07/27/determining-if-an-object-property-exists/) and wanted to share (after modification to fit my needs):

```
if ("property_name" in object_name && object_name.property_name !== undefined){
   // code..
}
```

So if I wanted to apply this on my example, it will look like:

```
if ("error_1" in errors && errors.error_1 !== undefined){
   // code..
}
```

Comment: the `in` operator looks down the property chain, so it might return unwanted results depending on the structure. `hasOwnProperty` checks the specified property as a **direct** property of that object

Answer (score -2):

In order to check whether the object is empty or not use this code.

```
if (Object.keys(object_name).length > 0) {

  // Your code

}
```

Comment: your code check if the object itself is empty, not the object property

Comment: not what the question is about